# Looking for a regex that only grabs up to the second " quote mark not any further

Tags: regex

I need a regex that grabs only up to the second quotation mark and nothing further.

```
img src=\"/uploadedImages/2012_December_OTW_Ocean Wave bottle.jpg\" alt=\"2010_JAN_OTW_Oceanbottle.jpg\"
```

I only need

```
img src=\"/uploadedImages/2012_December_OTW_Ocean Wave bottle.jpg\"
```

can anyone help me figure out a regex for this I have been struggling.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following regex :

```
^[^"]*"[^"]*"
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uG3mK2/1)

Comment: Thank you so much, I was so close and it was a matter of not enough quotes

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative character class:

```
"([^"]*)"
```

[***Demo.***](https://regex101.com/r/nC8hM4/1)